# Custom color in TeXworks

Tags: texworks

I followed this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383271/how-can-i-set-a-dark-theme-in-texworks) and similar pages in order to customize the color of text and background of TeXworks. I can change the background color

```
QTextEdit {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;            /* sets the main text color */
}
```

However, the keywords which are dark blue are shown good in the in the black background. How can I change the colors of keywords, numbers, strings and ...?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452579. You have to change the syntax theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Syntax colours are held in a file

> syntax-patterns.txt

which is deep in a subfolder in your user AppData path

In my case it is C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\TeXworks\0.6\configuration

As TeXnician has pointed out in his linked answer above on Linux this may be located at ~/.TeXworks/configuration/syntax-patterns.txt

for some hints see https://www.texdev.net/2009/11/13/background-colouring-in-texworks/
and TeXnicians answer at [How to change background colour in texworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452577/how-to-change-background-colour-in-texworks/452579#452579) (upvotes welcome)

If syntax colouring is not behaving as expected there may be related answers here

[Texworks syntax highlighting not working on windows 8 and 8.1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159062/texworks-syntax-highlighting-not-working-on-windows-8-and-8-1)
[package for making the script in MiKTeX colorful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185022/package-for-making-the-script-in-miktex-colorful)
https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=6921

The latest [manual source is here](https://github.com/TeXworks/manual/tree/master/src) and also check out  [Help with custom syntax highlighting for TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135130/help-with-custom-syntax-highlighting-for-texworks?rq=1)  For regex help the above links to https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Maybe to add: On Windows it's AppData, Linux and other operating systems have some configuration directory in the home folder.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks after answering I saw your main comment where a Linux path was shown but will add that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's more complete that way. Although I wonder if we have some extensive answer on configuring TeXworks syntax highlighting…

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for constructive comments, feel free to edit as you see fit.

Comment: No, that was really more a comment than anything else as I do not have any post in mind that would fit the description but I would not exclude the possibility that we have some post on the site that shows how to do syntax highlighting adjustments in TeXworks.