# How do I set TexWorks's cursor's width and color?

Tags: color, texworks

I know how to get TexWorks invoked with a command which specifies a stylesheet file. This contains specifications for some aspects of Qt objects, e.g.

```
QTextEdit {
    background-color: black;  
    color: white; 
}
```

I find TexWorks's cursor hard to find; how can I widen it? And change its color if this can be configured separately? (I fear that the latter is not possible and that the cursor is drawn merely by drawing its extent in reverse video.)

Comment: Perhaps this question would point in the right direction: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461680/custom-color-in-texworks

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sadly no: that question concerned the Tex keywords, and the information in its answer pointed to a different configuration file. That doesn't help w.r.t. the text cursor.